# Ability to tag regions for ‘Offers remote’ job postings

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

The company I work for uses Stack Overflow Jobs, and we allow remote work. As such, we make use of the ‘Offers remote’ perk on the job description so remote job seekers can easily find us.

While remote work is not tied to a specific location, there’s often still a need to hire within certain regions. For a variety of reasons (tax, time zones, etc) a company may prefer remote employees living in certain general areas - state, country, continent, timezone(s), etc.

In our case we’ve included our preferred locations (which are mostly timezone-based) in our job posting title. Unfortunately not all applicants see this and we receive a number of applications from outside our preferred regions.

Ideally we could tag our job postings with our preferred regions. And these preferred regions would be displayed on the job posting for applicants to see.

Thoughts on adding the option to set general regions to ‘Offers remote’ job postings?

Comment: Listings have advertising regions, that are used to increase the exposure of your listing to the most relevant applicants. If you’re seeing a high number of applicants outside your desired location, reach out to your sales rep who should be able to help.

Comment: Added an answer below, expanding on @g3rv4's comment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback! We've received similar feedback and are reviewing this in upcoming planning sessions. We'll report back here when we have a solution designed.

Answer (score 13):

Make sure to set your job's targeting region accordingly:

[image]

While the targeting region is currently not displayed on the job listing itself, we're doing our best not to advertise the job to candidates outside of the targeting region.

Candidates applying from outside of your targeting region (out-of-region candidates) are hidden by default on the *Applicants* page:

[image]

We're also working on another feature right now related to email notifications for out-of-region candidates (probably a weekly summary email instead of individual notifications), which is expected to ship next month.

Answer (score 3):

I see this all the time, just noticed a [recent US-only job](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/199636/ios-engineer-martiancraft?med=clc) with the remote tag. It's typical - when I was looking for jobs earlier this year a significant number of the remote jobs had regional or timezone restrictions.

How about a special case for the `remote` tag which reminds the advertiser of the option of targeting regions? The current system is apparently not providing enough prompting.

As a corollary, also consider that restricting timezones alone may be important to remote advertisers. That's not necessarily easy for them to map to geographical regions.

(sorry, I know this is strictly-speaking a *comment* rather than *answer* but wanted to provide more nuanced feedback than comments have room and capabilities for)