# Remote jobs and timezone search

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I noticed a welcome development on the job site as companies can list the timezone for remote jobs.

[image]

However, there doesn't seem to be a way to **add this as a search filter preference** so you only see remote jobs within the timezones you are comfortable working.

Second slightly less important is that this time zone preference gets a bit strange for some jobs:

[image]

Maybe this needs some enhancement on the job posting side as well? Possibly related to [Ability to tag regions for ‘Offers remote’ job postings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362424/ability-to-tag-regions-for-offers-remote-job-postings)

Comment: +1 for this feature request. It would significantly reduce recruiters work load, help candidates better identify roles.

Comment: +1 I've looking for that.